# msp430 using Button as switch

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, switches, msp430, energia

I am trying to do this(http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Switch) without using any external parts because I was able to use button example from same site with this code: http://en.textsave.org/VjL) with my msp430g2553 using Energia but its not working, any help?

```
const int buttonPin = PUSH2;     // the number of the pushbutton pin
const int ledPin =  GREEN_LED;   // the number of the LED pin

int state = HIGH;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading;           // the current reading from the input pin
int previous = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin

// the follow variables are long's because the time, measured in miliseconds,
// will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
long time = 0;         // the last time the output pin was toggled
long debounce = 200;   // the debounce time, increase if the output flickers

void setup(){
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);}

void loop(){
reading = digitalRead(ledPin);

// if the input just went from LOW and HIGH and we've waited long enough
// to ignore any noise on the circuit, toggle the output pin and remember
// the time
if (reading == HIGH && previous == LOW && millis() - time > debounce) {
if (state == HIGH){
  state = LOW;
}
else
  state = HIGH;
  time = millis();    }

digitalWrite(ledPin, state);
previous = reading;}
```

Comment: What isn't working about it, do you have a circuit diagram?

Comment: Did you manage to get Debounce working yet?

Comment: Is the buttonPin double as an analog input? If so, it's it set as a digital port? The datasheet suggests if it is configured as analog, the digital input will not function.

Comment: green led is just on and nothing happens when i press button, there are some schematics after page 18 : http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau318d/slau318d.pdf

Comment: i tried this : http://energia.nu/Tutorial_Debounce.html but nothing happens, if i change pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT); as pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); it works like that button example , i didnt even noticed that this is the same thing that i was trying to do.

Comment: DrRobotNinja, i have no idea what that means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eh, most likely you are using a rev1.5 Launchpad. The external pullup pin for the p1.3 button is not populated. Since it is not populated, there is no steady state change. You must enable the internal pullup.

Instead of `pinMode(buttonPin);` use `pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);`

Also, you are trying to read the wrong pin.

Instead of `reading = digitalRead(ledPin);` use `reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);`

Comment: nothing happens when i change it to pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); and reading = digitalRead(ledPin); is same in my code.

Comment: and yes i am using rev 1.5

Comment: @Cagurtay the reading part is wrong. **Think** about it...

Comment: Bah... I am sorry, i switched variables to my kit but accidently put output instead of input. reading = digitalRead(buttonPin); , thank you.